# Selecting tabBarItem causes title to disappear

Tags: xcode, ios4, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

Like a title, i have a view build with IB. When the app are lunched all work fine, but when i  select a tab bar item the title disappear!

Any idea?

sory for my bad english, i'm italian :D

UPDATE:
the title of the tabBarItem is taked by the viewController title, in this case

> self.title = @""

i have to make hidden the viewcontroller title

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It seems that you have gotten your problem solved by yourself. You should post it as an answer here so that people can refer to it later. Also, you should mark answers as correct so that people will want to answer other questions that you ask.

Comment: Since Kazzar probably won't come back I took the liberty of posting the answer for him.

Answer (score 3):

This simple line will also do the job :

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"";
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.title = @"MY TITLE";

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 44);
UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.text = @"NO TEXT";
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

(I tried `self.navigationItem.titleView = nil` or `self.navigationItem.titleView.hidden = YES` but without results.)